# If partially matching URL is found on page, get that URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am currently creating a Chrome extension,
and want to get any URLs on the page which start with "https://google.com".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following creates a list of URL's in the document that starts with "https://google.com"

```
var checkRE = new RegExp('^https://google.com');
var list = []
for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
    if(checkRE.test(document.links[i].href)) {
        list.push(document.links[i].href)
    }
}
console.log(list);
```

Comment: Thanks! But I forgot to add that I want it to get the link which contains "https://google.com". For example, "https://google.com/somethingsomething".

Comment: Iterate the list of URL's and use `contains()` method to check if it contains "google.com". I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but for me to be able to put urls into array [a], I need to be able to get not just "https://google.com", but urls that start with "https://google.com". This is my main issue.

Comment: Please explain your problem clearly. Edit your question.

Comment: Thanks so much, I've edited the question after reviewing your generous answers. Now I know exactly what my issue is.

Comment: Now the code creates a list of URL's in the document that starts with "https://google.com"